# Validator.ValidateObject() does not throw an error despite violating the StringLength data annotation

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I have a class that with a property annotated with `[StringLength(2)]` like the class shown below.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {

    }

    [StringLength(2)]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Why doesn't the following code to validate the object not throw an error? Shouldn't `ValidationException` be thrown?

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.MyProperty = "A string longer than 2 characters";
ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContext(f);
Validator.ValidateObject(f, validationContext);
```